# How to exclude a property only if it's null in Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, data-class

I have this POJO:

```
data class User(
    var uid: String? = null,
    @get:Exclude
    var name: String? = null
) : Serializable
```

If I construct an object like this:

```
docRef.set(User("longUid", null))
```

I get in the database an object with a single property. If I use:

```
docRef.set(User("longUid", "John"))
```

I get the same behavior. Is there any possibility to exclude the **name** property only if it's null? If I pass a real value I want the object to contain both values.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can remove `@Exclude` from your User POJO. What do you need it for other than what you are asking? When you have an `User` with no `name` property, you can simply create an `User` object avoiding `name` property:

```
val userA = User("longUid")
```

When you set a document with `userA` as shown above, you won't have a `name` field for it in Firestore. And when you get `userA` from Firestore applying `toObject(Class<T>)` function to your `DocumentSnapshot` it should return an object with no name, so your new User object's `name` would be `null`.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I just tried your solution but it doesn't work because if I pass only the id to the constructor, the name is null. So I get in the database a user with an id and the name property with null. I want only the id to be added and not the name with null.

Comment: @LisDya You could have 2 constructors in your user data class

Comment: If I have two constructors and I call the one with two, I pass null to the name, so I get null in the database as well.